# New tag merge thread

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

Starting a new thread akin to
[Should we start dealing with duplicate tags](https://economics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1370/should-we-start-dealing-with-duplicate-tags).

Post merge proposals under here. Unless convincing counterarguments or negative votes follow within a week, mods may consider merging the tags.

Answer (score 2):

IMO we should merge
[demography](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/demography) and [demographics](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/demographics), despite one being the science and the other the thing the science describes.